# sed duplicate first part of line into multiple places on the same line

Tags: replace, sed

I have a feeling what I'm trying to do is very simple, but my brain is just not coming up with the right way to manipulate it into working. There is a file with several thousand lines, each having a beginning part (the date and timestamp), and then one or more sets of values afterwards (including a MAC address, IP address, and username). I'm looking to use sed to take that first part and duplicate it to the beginning of each set of values on its own line. Here is an example:

Contents of the source file:

```
2013-08-02 11:33:32 (00:11:22:33:44:55, 10.8.12.13, ajones) (12:23:34:45:56:67, 10.8.23.34, msmith) (23:34:45:56:67:78, 10.8.44.33, hjohnson)
2014-09-22 14:43:02 (33:44:55:66:77:88, 10.8.98.99, brodriguez)
2015-10-31 04:43:39 (a2:4b:77:3c:32:91, 10.8.100.55, sthomas) (05:71:38:65:c4:7a, 10.8.81.43, ymcalister)
```

Would become:

```
2013-08-02 11:33:32 (00:11:22:33:44:55, 10.8.12.13, ajones)
2013-08-02 11:33:32 (12:23:34:45:56:67, 10.8.23.34, msmith)
2013-08-02 11:33:32 (23:34:45:56:67:78, 10.8.44.33, hjohnson)
2014-09-22 14:43:02 (33:44:55:66:77:88, 10.8.98.99, brodriguez)
2015-10-31 04:43:39 (a2:4b:77:3c:32:91, 10.8.100.55, sthomas)
2015-10-31 04:43:39 (05:71:38:65:c4:7a, 10.8.81.43, ymcalister)
```

I've been messing with global substitution on the line in conjunction with the hold space, but I can't find a way to give the hold contents as a substitution argument which would make this so much easier. Again, I'm sure there's something pretty basic that I'm not doing, but for the life of me I can't figure it out. Thanks for any help you can give!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how to do this with `sed`, but with `awk` you can do this:

```
awk -F\( '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) print $1 FS $i}' file
2013-08-02 11:33:32 (00:11:22:33:44:55, 10.8.12.13, ajones)
2013-08-02 11:33:32 (12:23:34:45:56:67, 10.8.23.34, msmith)
2013-08-02 11:33:32 (23:34:45:56:67:78, 10.8.44.33, hjohnson)
2014-09-22 14:43:02 (33:44:55:66:77:88, 10.8.98.99, brodriguez)
2015-10-31 04:43:39 (a2:4b:77:3c:32:91, 10.8.100.55, sthomas)
2015-10-31 04:43:39 (05:71:38:65:c4:7a, 10.8.81.43, ymcalister)
```

I do set the Field Separator to `(` then for all fields print first field and next in the loop to the end.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/^(\S+ \S+) \([^)]*\)/&\n\1/;/\(/P;D' file
```

Comment: @BMW I don't see why?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `D` command to set up a recursive loop.  We essentially store the date in the hold space and we print it out before we go to print the information.  If there is more than one piece of information on one line, we insert a newline at the end of the information, print it out, and delete everything up to the newline with `D` which also restarts the cycle.

```
/[[:date:]]/ { x; d; g; s/\([[:date:]]\) .*/\1/; x; s/[[:date:]] \(.*\)/\1/ }
x; p; x
s/[[:info:]]/&\n/
P
D
```

Where `[[:date:]]` and `[[:info:]]` are the regexes for the date and information respectively.